# Triggering event of C++ dll in unreal engine

Tags: c++, events, unreal-engine4, eventhandler

I am trying to use dll which reads incoming messages with a thread.Importing into unreal engine with Blueprint class, As I can't get the incoming messages. I am planning to have a event in the dll for which I'll put event handler in unreal engine code.

Can you please help me, Is this possible If it is how to work with it ?

I am trying something like this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576944/triggering-event-in-c-sharp-from-c-dll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dll code

```
EventCallback   OnEvent = NULL;
DLL_EXPORT void  WINAPI SetEventCallback(EventCallback func)
{
    OnEvent = func;
}
DLL_EXPORT void WINAPI FireEvent()
{
    if (OnEvent)
        OnEvent();
}
```

In Unreal engine code

```
typedef void(*_getSetEventCallback)(EventCallback);
_getSetEventCallback m_getSetEventCallbackFromDll=NULL;

void CALLBACK HandleEvent()
{   
     FString fstringVar = "Triggered by Event in dll";
     UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%s"), fstringVar);
}

void UVectorDll::importSetEventCallback()
{
    if (c_dllHandle != NULL)
    {
        FString procName = "SetEventCallback";    // Needs to be the exact name of the DLL method.
        m_getSetEventCallbackFromDll = (_getSetEventCallback)FPlatformProcess::GetDllExport(c_dllHandle, *procName);
        m_getSetEventCallbackFromDll(HandleEvent);
    }
}
```

**FireEvent can be done by dll or from Unreal Engine**